# It is possible to know what rating user provided on our app? using InAppReview lib provided by Google

Tags: android, google-play

I am going to start implementing the In-App-Review feature in my app. But I would like to know **what rating is given by the user** after showing a Review dialog. It is possible? And What is the **time bound** set by Google play to show the InAppReview popup next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment.

The documentation over [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#launch-review-flow) states that the callback after the [launchReviewFlow](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#launch-review-flow) is completed returns nothing.

```
flow.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
    // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
    // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
});
```

If you feel that the information is important to you, consider raising a feature request.